# Database design for normalizing database with unique id's to build a number

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Big question - I have a student number that is 10 digits long and it comes from three different database tables.  For example the student number would be 0012011234 with the corresponding values:

```
0012 = school id
01 = class id
1234 = student id
```

Can someone give me an idea of how to set this database up to auto increment and build these student numbers?  Right now I have three different database tables (schools, classrooms, students) and obviously they all need to be unique.  I'm working in C# and am having a hard time figuring out how to auto increment the classrooms & students as the correlate to schools.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is not a good method like D Stanley said, I would say you could write a scalar-valued function to that takes the top values from these tables and combines to form your desired value

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNewID
(

)
RETURNS NVarChar(15)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @result NVarChar(15)

    DECLARE  @SchoolId int
            ,@ClassId int
            ,@StudentId int 

    SELECT TOP 1 @SchoolId=ID FROM SchoolTable
    SELECT TOP 1 @StudentId=ID FROM StudentTable
    SELECT TOP 1 @ClassId=ID FROM ClassTable

    SET @RESULT = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,(@SchoolId+1)) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,(@ClassId+1)) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,(@StudentId+1)) 
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @result
```

Then use this function `dbo.GetNewID()` to get the latest ID

Comment: If you application can add new classes, students and schools simultaneously, there could be ID conflicts. This scenario works only if there is a single Admin

Answer (score 3):

You can't (and shouldn't) use autoincrement for this.  This should be done by the application that adds students.  If there are multiple apps that can add students, put that logic in a separate library (or web service) that the apps can share.

This is usually called a "smart identifier" and is not what autoincrement was designed for.

To do this in the app, I would just query each table when you add a new record and choose the `id` as `max(id) + 1` for each group (school or class).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. This application will be the only application that will be creating schools, classrooms, and students. Any c# code to make this happen?

Comment: That would be too much code for this forum.  I'd think about how you'd do it manually and start coding that way, coming back here if you are stuck on specific parts.

Comment: Alternatively use a stored procedure such that the creation is centralized in the database; only allow users to execute the stored procedure, not insert into the tables.

Answer (score 3):

I think your basic model is flawed.

Students can attend more than one class, and possibly more than one school. Its also quite common for schools to share facilities so a class could have students from more than one school.

You should run separate series of ids for students, schools and classes then add two relation ship tables `school_x_class` and `student_x_class`.

This should cover all eventualities.

Comment: In this particular scenario a student can only be in one class at a time.  Our program requires that a student be in one class however there are multiple classes in each school. Does that make sense?

Comment: I can almost guarantee that as soon as this system goes live you will get a "we are trying to add a student who attends two classes" support call.